# Allow only a specific country to be shown in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using `react-native-maps` in my React Native project and I want the map to show only Germany and dhe user should zoom in and out up to a certain level but always withing Germany. I don't want the user to be able to navigate to other countries.

I checked the documentation but I didn't find anything related to my problem. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you'll really need to 'bodge' this as it's not really true functionality of native maps.

You can limit the `maxZoom` level, to ensure that they cannot zoom passed a certain point - this will help with zooming. As for scrolling outside of a certain area - you can hitch onto the `onDrag` event, and check the lat and lon object. If the coordinates are outside a specific boundary, you can take the user back to a specified location - or present a user error? Geo fencing seems like it could be a part of this also.

Apart from theoretical - I'm afraid I've never done this, so cannot show you any implementation.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking to keep track of the coordinates and zoom level and "bring the user back inside" if he/she is out of the allowed region. I was wondering if there was any easier way though. Thanks!